# Is it risky to change hardcoded STP mLAG port cost on Cisco Nexus LACP port

Tags: cisco, spanning-tree, cisco-nexus, ieee-802.1ax, vpc

When two Cisco Nexus are connected in VPC, the stp cost is hardcoded to 200 for the mLAG LACP ports.
I would like to manually change the cost on my devices because my 2G and 200G links have the same cost and it could lead to saturations and errors.

Do you know if it's OK to do this, or if there is drawbacks / risks?

Edit: it is the port cost I want to change.
See "The STP port cost is fixed to 200 in a vPC environment." [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/6-x/interfaces/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Interfaces_Configuration_Guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Interfaces_Configuration_Guide_chapter_0111.html).
STP apart, I'd want to know if there is some Cisco thing about to break if I change the port cost.

Answer (score 2):

The current standard for STP link cost is IEEE 802.1Q which uses the basic rule *20 Tbit/s divided by link speed*. `200` corresponds to 100 Gbit/s for either a single link or a LAG based on 100G.

Aggregated link cost is calculated at their single speed by standard. Some platforms/vendors use a lower default port priority for LAG in order to prefer aggregated links over single links.

So, if the default VPC cost causes an undesired active topology, you could change the cost manually - I wouldn't change it otherwise. Alternatively you could use port priorities - which one is better depends on your physical topology, your overall architecture and policies which we know nothing about.

If your network is configured consistently, there shouldn't be any risk. The spanning tree might need realigning which might cause short-term blocking of non-edge ports - all depending on your topology. The STP cost is only relevant for STP, so nothing else breaks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my first post so my question is more specific.

Comment: @setenforce1 I have added a bit more information above. ;-)